# Ubuntu 23.04 second monitor not working

Tags: drivers, hardware, additional-drivers

I'm using my ubuntu 23.04 as a dual boot aside windows
the thing is the system won't recognize my second monitor which is connected via a HDMI cable
I have used several options in the Additional Driver section which some of them caused a new issue of not finding my network adapter so I was forced to delete them
I have tried some other distros and i had the same problem
Can anyone help me to make this work ?